# Why do we need to provide password in datasource?

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource

I just want to understand how the database connection work through datasource.

When we set up data source, we need to provide username/password.  However, if you want to retrieve a connection through datasource, we still supply another user name/password.

```
datasource.getConnection(username,password)
```

vs

```
datasource.getConnection();
```

Why do we do that?  is that redundancy?

I hope someone can help me to clarify that.

Comment: Consider better tagging for your question, its wording is very generic and nobody can guess what language and libraries you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think so : 
this is the code to get a connection via DataSource:

```
try {

    Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
    DataSource datasource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_CONTEXT);
    Connection con = datasource.getConnection();
    }catch(Exception e) {}
```

Now here I did not supply the uname/passw when obtaining a connection, as they are already specified in mysql-ds.xml [ my environ jboss , mysql ].

without JNDI:

```
oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource ds = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
ds.setDriverType("thin");
ds.setServerName("localhost");
ds.setPortNumber(1521);
ds.setDatabaseName("XE"); // Oracle SID
Connection con = ds.getConnection(user, password);
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  how about this api: datasource.getConnection(username,password)

Comment: if you are not using JNDI then you can use datasource.getConnection(username,password) ; I just added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a multi-user system, it is possible that the data source is deployed using one id/pwd and connections are obtained by different users (different user id/pwd) using the same deployed data source.

Comment: We have exactly that in my company.